# addEventListener event not showing the popup size correct in Google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am working on project that uses twitter4j API.I need to connect Twitter with my application.

https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=UHQ0f8KtX2yaNoY1oneZoQDmXTW5Pie3TQjNZb6Q.

This is the url of the popup I need on a button click.

I was using

window.open(PAGE.authURL,"twitterAuthWin", "status = 1, width = 800, resizable = 0")

command and it seems like blocked by popup blocker in Google chrome.

I solved this problem by changing the command to

document.getElementById("authtwitacc").addEventListener("click",function({window.open(PAGE.authURL,"twitterAuthWin", "status = 1, width = 800, resizable =0");},false)

Now the popup blocker doesnt block my popup in any browser and I am happy.

I still have an issue with the size of the popup only in chrome.It is not showing the actual size.

I need
width = 800 as I am specified in the command.All other browsers are working fine.Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: add innerWidth = 800 beside width = 800

Comment: Sorry.This is not working for me.The popup coming as new window.

Comment: The popup is coming for other browsers.But I am not able to add Twitter account anyway.Means that it is redirected to http://localhost:8080/authTwitter?oauth_token=xQX038fd4PSe0LSKRpfdkwTqdNwkNaBhaUQbCFGuMg&oauth_verifier=Scv8vOhhj0krg5xQLYvosazczezWJvo9vEEwzDPmL6E